# when i add video youtube i got error when it is empty

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-video-player

i got red screen when the fvideo is empty

```
  late YoutubePlayerController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
        final videoID = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.fvideo);
        setState(() {
          _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
            initialVideoId: videoID!,
            flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
              autoPlay: false,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose(); // Dispose the controller only if it's not null
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                if (widget.fvideo.isNotEmpty && _controller != null)
                  YoutubePlayer(
                    controller: _controller!,
                    showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                    bottomActions: [
                      CurrentPosition(),
                      ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
                    ],
                  )
                else
                  Text('No video provided'), // Display a message if no video URL is provided
              ],
```

i try to add if statment in the controller but i go controller error , when there is a video the code run success, when it is empty i got the problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ3Yw.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the videoID is not null inside initState()? you should check that too

Comment: its null when i add if statment to check if fvideo is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your videoID is null, thats why you are getting the "null check operator used on a null value" error. You should check if the videoID is null or not, using the if statement or ternary conditional operator (if you have some default videoId to set).

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  final videoID = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.fvideo);

  // Check if videoID is not null before creating the controller
  if (videoID != null) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: videoID,
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: false,
        ),
      );
    });
  } else {
    print('Invalid video URL: ${widget.fvideo}');
  }
}
```